# How to set linphone to connect with TLS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linphone

I'm trying to register with TLS connection . I changed the transport type to TLS but failed to register . I have read about TLS handshake but I have no idea how to set it with liblinphone.
I tried to get a server certificate with command

> openssl s_client -connect xxxxx.com:443 |tee logfile

and add it to rootca file in linphone project but it's not working . The free sip server that i tried is sip2sip.info

Comment: could you please share the linphone code? i mean the code that you have converted as a framework/static library

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_L2ss6F25K-S0Ribk84WjNfRzQ . In this zip file It contain a static library and app project to call a library . I finished only register part .

Comment: it doesn't have access

Comment: Try again.I edited a permission

Comment: Sorry. i hope, if you edit, you may need to give new link

Comment: Try this one : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4gtgiY3w5xySlZyOTdXcmRtQW8

Comment: Its working. this may also help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253641/convert-c-submodule-included-objective-c-project-linphone-as-a-framework-or/44396977#44396977

Comment: Ok. Thank you.If you know how to set liblinphone to test with TLS please let me know.

Comment: Me too tried "sip2sip.info" . getting Registration failure with message "Cannot reach the server. either it is an invalid address or it may be temporary down
"

Comment: In my case, we are using UDP with our own sip server and its working. we use our own API for signup, and signing with linphone app.

Comment: My problem is solved.when I changed to test with Brekeke free sip server.Now I can register/invite and so on with udp tcp tls.

Comment: Glad to hear that, thanks for sharing about Brekeke