# iOS linphone-SDK after adding run script error

Tags: ios, swift, linphone, linphone-sdk

My project use cocoa pods to manager third library.

And I incorporating linphone-SDK in my object.

When I adding run script after embedded linphone frameworks,my project show some errors.

I listed the messages as below.

```
fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/zcon21/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/path/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire (No such file or directory)

rm: /Users/zcon21/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/flyingSoul-client-eaugkyhuzdcucvcjxkgjqyewjspt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/flyingSoul-client.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: No such file or directory

mv: rename /Users/zcon21/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/flyingSoul-client-eaugkyhuzdcucvcjxkgjqyewjspt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/flyingSoul-client.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire-merged to /Users/zcon21/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/flyingSoul-client-eaugkyhuzdcucvcjxkgjqyewjspt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/flyingSoul-client.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: No such file or directory
```

It looks like third library problems.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W9XH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUIFs.png)

How can I fix it?

Please help me out.

Comment: Clear derived data and do a "clean build folder". did u add linphone-SDK path in build settings or drag and dropped into project?

Comment: @ShebinKoshy
I try clear derived data and "clean build folder" , but not work. Also add path in build setting. And a strange thing, if I move my project in to linphone project. linphone project show same errors,but it can build success!!

Comment: Are you using linphone-SDK or linphone project?

Comment: How did you integrate your project into linphone project? better remove your cocoa pod dependancy. use carthage instead. it seems you are using Alamofire. and it support carthage too. i know its not a proper answer for ur question. but u can achieve ur target. As per my knowledge, linphone uses run script only for making the SDK.

Comment: @ShebinKoshy I drag and dropped swift file to linphone project and setting third library. And third library not only Alamofire, I just fetch a section, but the errors are same. Run script I reference linphone-iphone's readme.

Comment: @ShebinKoshy I guess I found the reason, the run script will execute all libraries to do slim down, so show the errors, but will not affect app running.

Comment: Did u successfully run the linphone application alone?

Comment: I ignore this problem,because I need to coding some shell script  to fix it,but I don't know how to coding shell script now. APP can run.

Comment: This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253641/convert-c-submodule-included-objective-c-project-linphone-as-a-framework-or . As of my remembrance, I dint use any scripts. in my case, my main project was written in both objective c and swift. I achieved it by integrating the linphone project and sdk into my main project.

Comment: @ShebinKoshy Thanks a lot. After I compile linphone SDK .I saw document has framework. So I embedded linphone's .framework. I'm not sure is this new way? I read some articles all teach embedded linphone's .a file. But I saw the linphone-iphone project is using .frameworks now.

Comment: http://www.jianshu.com/p/3e12033afe12

Comment: @ShebinKoshy new update: I check the run script's option:'Run script only when installing ' ,The Error was disappears and APP can work.

Comment: Great job...... :) Is there anything else?